# Apps for using iPad as a video reference monitor

Tags: ipad, foley, video-reference, app, field-recording

I've begun using my iPad as a video reference monitor when I record source material and foley, as it's completely silent and very mobile. Right now I'm using dropbox to transfer and play the videos, but it doesn't work quite as well as I would like it to. For one, when I scrub it will sometimes start to re-buffer the video, and the controls aren't very good in general.

I was wondering if there are any apps that are build specifically for this purpose?
Best case scenario, something that allow me to easily loop a section or make time markers, but anything that has a better workflow than the native video player would be great.

And if you know any other great iPads for when working in the field, feel free to share them too. It's an amazing tool for the field, and I would hate to waste its potential :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a second application to do this. Run AirDisplay on your iOS device and computer, and simply show the Quicktime window (and transport controls, if there's no one operating the computer for you) in your DAW on it as a 2nd (or 3rd, or Nth) screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To me the point of the iPad is to not have to rely on bringing my computer everywhere I go to record (I should mention that when I record foley, I'm usually not at home). Besides, Air Display doesn't excactly make the interface more responsive. I do use it sometimes though, so not a bad idea at all. Just not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded an app called "Touch The Video"- Was a couple bucks, works very well for what I need.  It allows you to add markers and gives you more control over the transport.  I also love the ipad for recording foley in the field.  I've got my ipad wirelessly transmitting guide track to my recorder, which makes it very easy to sync the recordings with my session.

Comment: expand on your last point please! how do you do that?

Comment: Basically, I've got my mic on a stand, recording to channel 1, and I took the headphone out of the ipad, connected to a wireless transmitter going into channel 2.  Watch the video, Record the Feet. I've got it set up where I can hear my mic in the right ear and the video in the left. When it comes time to sync, just drop the recording into Pro Tools, line up the guide tracks(doesn't have to be frame accurate, just close enough), get rid of the second track, edit the foley til your happy with sync,  and you're done!

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to an old question like this. That app is perfect, just what I was looking for! And to think. I was still looking :-)